# How long can Android Camera2 run?

Tags: android-camera2, tflite

I'm a bit new to running Camera on Android devices, so I want to ask this quite unfamiliar question. How long can camera operate using the Camera2 API, so that it run continuously even from day to day? If so, is that efficient though?

A bit of context, I'm currently involved in a project that plans to use the camera continuously and run Pose Estimation on that image input (using TFlite API) to detect some poses (not determined yet) that can be interesting to trigger some actions (for instance - initiate conversation with a smart speaker). Thus, we want to have the camera as well as the model work continuously for a long time to collect data & trigger action whenever possible. However, we tested and the app crashes after about 9 hours of operation. Therefore, I doubted if it's some bug, or is it even possible for the camera itself & the model to run continuously & efficiently? It would be good if there's anyone familiar with using the Camera2 API, and if possible, using ML model, to give me some advice on this. Thank you very much :')

Answer (score 0):

I think there are couple of points I could suggest. I assume you tried running the device with stock(built in) camera app and it can run as long as you want. Because if that cannot run, odds to succeed are relatively low.

1. Guard against overheating. Depending on your ML model, image processing can heat some devices up pretty fast and this would cause Android OS to send a kill signal to the app. I experienced this issue mostly on Google Pixel devices but there are many devices have the same issue.
2. Other point would be memory management. Make sure you don't load your TFLite models every time a new frame comes but only once at the very beginning. I think you can monitor memory usage with android studio memory profiler.
3. Reduce the frame rate of the camera. If it will not damage your use case, set the camera fps to minimum. You might not need constant 30ps. You can even think of reducing frame resolution. If all could work with 640x480, try that.
4. Find/develop a simple ML model that will recognise action vs idle. Run your pose detection model only if there is an action on the scene. You can even use a simple face detector maybe? Something like: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector
5. Find a way to optimize bitmap conversions you might have been doing. YUV to RGB conversion for example might be costly. You might want to use a library like OpenCV for processing the images.